# I am getting "Error to many values to unpack expecting 1"

Tags: python, syntax-error

When I use my search if statement I get an error. To many values to unpack expected 1. How should I proceed I have tried to switch things around. Thanks for any advice. I just started coding so go easy on me please. Thanks.

```
 #Map
 contacts = {}
 #Intro
 print("Address book to store friends contact")
 print("-" * 50)
 print("-" * 50)
 while True:
 #Display of options
     print("Select an option: ")
     print("1-Add/Update contact")
     print("2- Display all contacts")
     print("3- Search")
     print("4- Delete contact")
     print("5- Quit")

     #Selection
     option = input("Select which one you would like to choose. Ex. Select an option. Type here:  ")


  #Main program

     if option == "Add/Update contact":
         person_added = input("Who would you like to be updated or added")
         next_question = input("What is there contact information")
    #The code below will add the person to the list or update them
         contacts[person_added] = next_question

     elif option == "Display all contacts":
         print(contacts)
         print("-" * 50)
         print(" " * 50)

     elif option == "Search":
         search_question = str(input("Who are you looking for: "))
         for search in contacts.items():
             if search == str(search_question):
                 print("I found" + search)
             else:
                 print("Contact not found")

     elif option == "Delete contact":
          person_deleted = input("Who would you like to be deleted ")
         del(contacts[person_deleted])
         print("I just deleted " + person_deleted)

     else:
          print("Thank You for using ME! Goodbye")
          break
```

Comment: It would help if you post the full error here. Python errors give a lot of inforamtion to start with like the exact line and place in that line where the error occured

Comment: `for search in contacts.items():` -- is the problematic line. items returns a pair of key, value

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: I figured it out thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post your answer, there's nothing more frustrating than finding someone with the same problem saying 'I figured it out' with no answer

Comment: So please delete this question. As this post didn't help you, it will certainly won't help anyone else arriving here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
search_question = str(input("Who are you looking for: "))
for search in contacts.items():
    if search == str(search_question):
        print("I found" + search)
    else:
        print("Contact not found")
```

Here is one problem. The `.items()` method returns pairs `(key, value)`, and so adding `search` to a string in the first `print` statement will cause problems. Also, the code is a bit inefficient, which we can also fix:

```
search_question = input("Who are you looking for: ")
if search_question in contacts:
    print("I found" + search_question)
else:
    print("Contact not found")
```

`input()` already returns a string, so we don't need to try to convert it with `str()`. Also, if `b` is a dictionary, then `a in b` will return whether `a` is a key of `b`, which is exactly the behavior we desire.